# JSON.stringify not working when comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two arrays and check if they are the same. According to the logic below the function should return DRAW as the arrays I am comparing to are exactly the same. It returns undefined instead. I cannot figure it out why it doesn't return draw. If I change the && to || it returns draw so I assume there is an issue with the logical operator.

```js
function isSolved(board) {

  // TODO: Check if the board is solved!
  var arraya = [1,1,1];
  var arrayb = [2,2,2];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
  
    for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        return false;
      } else if (
        (JSON.stringify(board[i]) === JSON.stringify(arraya))
        && (JSON.stringify(board[i]) ===JSON.stringify(arrayb))) {
        return "draw"
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}
    
console.log(
  isSolved([
    [1,1,1],
    [1,2,2],
    [2,2,2]
  ])
);
```

Comment: if you look at your conditions, you are checking if the value is equal to zero (none in the board is) else if the value is both equal to a string representation of the array a AND array b at the same time.  Your logic here seems flawed and needs to be revised

Comment: In fact, board[i] can not equal two difference values at the same time. For example, (a === 1) && (a === 2) is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` like this:

```js
var arraya = [1,1,1];
var arrayb = [2,2,2];

function isSolved(a, b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) ? "draw" : false;
};

var input = [[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [2,2,2]];

for (var item of input) {
  console.log(isSolved(item, arraya));
  console.log(isSolved(item, arrayb));
  console.log("=====");
}
```